# npm run start:dev in NestJs not to rebuild when i make some change in my code

Tags: npm, nestjs

When I run `npm run start:dev` in NestJs it works like this:

```
10:00:00 AM - Starting compilation in watch mode...

10:00:10 AM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/0cb76900-3b46-4f68-82c0-ea78ed36f327
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[Nest] 3932   - 03/06/2020, 10:00:23 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 3932   - 03/06/2020, 10:00:23 AM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +41ms
[Nest] 3932   - 03/06/2020, 10:00:23 AM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 3932   - 03/06/2020, 10:00:23 AM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +2ms
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUh0m.png)

But when I changed the code it was not rebuilt. It just shows like this:

```
10:40:27 AM - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

10:40:27 AM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87LfQ.png)

Can anyone help me to fix it? Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you provide the command you are using? Also have you tried deleting the destination folder? Typescript compilation with `incremental` flag has chance to get in inconsistent state.

Comment: add the start:dev command please

Comment: I use ```start:dev:nest start --watch``` in NestJs.

Answer (score 4):

It has something to do with Circular Dependency as stated here: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency. Simply means some module which are depended on each other are called recursively which as I learnt from  https://stackoverflow.com/users/8966778/ruslan-gonzalez in the NestJs community, makes the app fail from starting up which he also helped me fix.

If you can create a minimal repo and share the link, so I can check it for you

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a lot of time, although I didn't have a circular reference - while doing some refactoring I removed a module from the app module imports which caused this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the logging is not being shown is because you may have the logger disable in your configuration since the tsc shows that compiling is fine but nothing else, checkout the main.ts file and enable the logger.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger: false,
  });
```

to

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked for me by deleting the dist folder and recompiling the project

Answer (score -2):

In my case i realised that I didn't save my code ,

Nestjs will only re-compile a code if it notices any changes ,Incase of no changes it won't ,so it's possible you didn't save your code on ur code editor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).